# Stabbing and running, how are they related?

Tags: etymology, phrasal-verbs

When you literally *run through* some where, e.g.

> I have run through the streets of London

it is quite clear what is meant.

At a slightly more figurative level one might say,

> I will run through our procedures with you.

This is also clear. One is teaching another something quickly, as if to make their mind run through the information.

But if I were a pirate and I found a dead body, I might say

> He's been run through with a cutlass!

Now, I know that *to run through* means *to stab all 
the way through the body*, but how has *run through* come to mean that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Run through* in that sense is first found used by John Lydgate in the fifteenth century, but *run* alone can also mean ‘stab’ and is found for the first time in the work of the same author. Given the sense of *run* as some kind of rapid movement, its use to describe the act of penetrating the flesh with a blade may be understandable. *Running through* seems to perform the operation more conclusively.